# How to stop the Kafka Listener beans from outside the application?

Tags: spring, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

If there are Kafka Consumers running on a server, is it possible to selectively stop the listener beans from outside the application, by a REST service for example??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using spring-kafka (which you tagged), yes; see [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#kafkalistener-lifecycle).

You can start and stop all or individual listeners using the `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry`.

Comment: Okay. But is it possible to stop individual listeners using the KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry from outside the application? I'm trying to build a REST service which will have 2 endpoints - /start and /stop - which will either start or stop the specific beans(that belong to a different application) at runtime.

Comment: You need to add the rest endpoint to the actual kafka application (not another), just auto wire the registry into your controller, give each lisrtener an id, then call `registry.getListenerContainer(id).stop()`.

Comment: Or you could add a topic for control purposes and add a listener on that topic to each application. Your rest application can then send command messages over that topic.

Comment: Thanks Gary. I added the rest endpoint to the Kafka consumer application and I'm able to start/stop the listener containers based on their IDs now.