# Force Kafka client to stop reading messages from a topic

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I have the following situation: i use kafka template in order to interact with Kafka but i would like to be able programatically to prevent the Kafka client from reading messages from a certain topic but still be able to produce to other topic.
Is there any way in which this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start and stop listeners when needed - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66120928/how-to-stop-the-kafka-listener-beans-from-outside-the-application/66122979#66122979).

You can set up ACLs to secure topics, if that's what you mean by "prevent".

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_authz

Comment: the first link is useful, however i would like to add that in order for this to work, people should know how to add a listener and only after that the listener can be stopped/paused/resumed etc.